# jQuery UI resizable with jQuery floatThead plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to make column resizing work with [floatThead](http://mkoryak.github.io/floatThead/) . I tried using jquery resizable and colResizable plugins but in vain. Does anyone know any example implementation of **resizable columns** with floatThead?

I am using the following configuration for floatThead.

```
        useAbsolutePositioning: false,
        autoReflow: false,
        headerCellSelector: "tr:first>th:visible",
        zIndex: 10,
        debounceResizeMs: 300,
        scrollContainer: function ($table) {
            return $table.closest('div');
        }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggling with similar problems now for 3 hours and I finaly solved it!

My problem was that the min-width in px on the table set by the floatThead script made it impossible to scale down the parent element with jQuery UI resizable. It was only possible to scale up.

My solution is to disable floatThead on resizing and enable it again after.
Probably you want to add code to store the scroll state.

```
    var resizeId;

    $("YourResizableParent").on( "resize", function( event, ui ) {

        //Disabeling floatThead removes the min-width on the table
        $("#assignment-table").floatThead('destroy');

        //Fire function after resizing is finished
        clearTimeout(resizeId);
        resizeId = setTimeout(doneResizing, 500);           

    });

    function doneResizing(){
        //Initiate floatThead again         
        $('#assignment-table').floatThead(); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, and in my case it was all because of simple mistake.

I was attaching resizer to both of my original table and the ghost table created by floatThead plugin. Then I was unable to resize anything.

So my advice is: Always init resizable **before** you init floatThead, then all works just fine